# ImportError: cannot import name Ghost

Tags: python

I know there are similar questions, but I could not find a solution for this one. Here is what I have done.

I installed the ghost module using pip. The site-packages/ghost folder has 3 files  `__init__.py`, `ghost.py` and `test.py`.

`__init__.py` has the following content

```
from ghost import Ghost
from test import GhostTestCase
```

module suggests the method

```
from ghost import Ghost
```

But it throws the following error.

```
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from ghost import ghost
  File "G:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ghost\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ghost import Ghost
ImportError: cannot import name Ghost
```

I tried adding the path to PYTHONPATH; it didn't work. I can't figure out why it is happening with a standard module.I am working in python 3.3

Comment: the `ghost` module is a your module? probably there is a conflict between names

Comment: @gipi I didnt make the module,I am using the python module ghost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Python 3, try changing that line in `__init__.py` to

```
from .ghost import Ghost
```

to do a package-relative import. If that works, it's a bug in the module and you should [report it](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/issues).

Answer (score 2):

What was you pip command line? Should be `pip install Ghost.py`
and not `pip install ghost`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

If the script file is named `ghost.py` or `Ghost.py`, you have to rename them to a name other than `ghost`.

After that you have to delete the `.pyc` files that have been made by the previous scripts.

Now you can run your code.

Answer (score -1):

Did you make a typo requesting

```
    from ghost import ghost
```

instead of

```
    from ghost import Ghost
```

Making the module ghost try to import "ghost" instead of "Ghost" giving out an error?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I checked the module,But the Object name is "Ghost" itself..and not "ghost".

Comment: I'll try installing it in Python 3.3 and see if it raises the same problem.

Comment: When it throws the error does it give you a specific error such as ImportError? If so, what exactly does it say after it?

Comment: yes it was "ImportError: cannot import name Ghost".As suggested by nneonneo it was an issue with the module